# Partial derivative of probability density function and maximum likelihood estimate

Tags: probability, partial-derivative, maximum-likelihood

While studying some paper, I am curious about the following solution.
The probability density function is given as below. ($\sigma$, and $\alpha$ can be treated as constants. $X,Y$ are column vectors with size N)

$$L(X,Y|v,\gamma) =
\frac{1}{\{(2\pi)^2\sigma^2[\sigma^2+\alpha^4\frac{v}{2}(1+\gamma^2)]\}^N} \exp\left\{−\frac{1}{2\sigma^2[\sigma^2+\alpha^4\frac{v}{2}(1+\gamma^2)]}[(\sigma^2+\alpha^4\frac{v}{2}\gamma^2)X^HX-2\gamma\alpha^4\frac{v}{2}Re\{X^HY\}+(\sigma^2+\alpha^4\frac{v}{2})Y^HY]\right\}.$$

To get the maximum likelihood estimate of $\gamma$, we solve the following partial derivatives.
$$\frac{\partial logL}{\partial \gamma}=0, \frac{\partial logL}{\partial v}=0,$$
The papar says that we get the following quadratic equation.
$$\gamma^2Re\{X^HY\} - \gamma Y^HY + \gamma X^HX - Re\{X^HY\}=0$$
I tried to get this final quadratic equation, but I couldn't. I only got a fifth degree equation. Maybe something is wrong. Does anybody help me?

Comment: You can get the right typesetting for $\log$ just like you got it for $\exp$, using a backslash: `\log`.